# Login page error: 'http' does not exist (HTML / TypeScript / Angular2 / Javascript)

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular

Screenshot of error:

[image]

Link to full project:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/2aqrv63tmv3avnd/FullProject2.zip?dl=0

Link to plunker example of log-in page:

http://plnkr.co/edit/j69yu9cSIQRL2GJZFCd1?p=preview

(For the example the username and password is "test")

Code containing the error:

```
  return this.http.post('/auth/login', JSON.stringify({}
```

Full code of dashboard.component.ts

```
import {Component, OnInit} from 'angular2/core';
import {Router} from 'angular2/router';
import {Hero} from './hero';
import {HeroService} from './hero.service';
import {RouteConfig, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/router';
import {HeroesComponent} from './heroes.component';
import {HeroDetailComponent} from './hero-detail.component';
import {SpreadSheetComponent} from './spreadsheeteditall.component';
import {SwitchUsersComponent} from './SwitchUsers.component';
import {BiddingPageComponent} from './BiddingPage.component';
import { Injectable } from 'angular2/core';
import { Jsonp, URLSearchParams } from 'angular2/http';
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS, Http, Headers} from 'angular2/http';
import {JSONP_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/http';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-dashboard',
  templateUrl: 'app/dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['app/dashboard.component.css'],
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
  providers : [HTTP_PROVIDERS, Http],
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
  heroes: Hero[] = [];

  constructor(private _http: Http, private _heroService: HeroService, private _router: Router) {
        this.token = localStorage.getItem('token');
   }

  ngOnInit() {
    this._heroService.getHeroes().then(heroes => this.heroes = heroes.slice(1,5));
  }

  gotoDetail(hero: Hero) {
    let link = ['HeroDetail', { id: hero.id }];
    this._router.navigate(link);
  }
  @Injectable()

  token: string;


  login(username: String, password: String) {


   return this.http.post('/auth/login', JSON.stringify({}
   // username: username,
   //  password: password
   //  }), {
   //   headers: new Headers({
    //   'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  //  })
  //  })

    //  .map((res : any) => {
    //    let data = res.json();
    //    this.token = data.token;
    //    localStorage.setItem('token', this.token);
    //  });

    //  for the purpose of this cookbook, we will juste simulate that

    if (username === 'test' && password === 'test') {
      this.token = 'token';
      localStorage.setItem('token', this.token);
      //return Rx.Observable.of('token');
    }

    //return Rx.Observable.throw('authentication failure');
  ,

  logout() {

   }}
/*
    return this._http.get(this.config.serverUrl + '/auth/logout', {
      headers: new Headers({
        'x-security-token': this.token
      })
    })
    .map((res : any) => {
      this.token = undefined;
      localStorage.removeItem('token');
    });


 //   this.token = undefined;
 //   localStorage.removeItem('token');

   // return Rx.Observable.of(true);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (`_http` instead `http`):

```
return this._http.post('/auth/login', JSON.stringify({}
```